# Groovy: Sorting Columns in a view: list

Tags: grails, listview, groovy, sorting

I have a Groovy application. I am rendering the view list using the following statement:

```
render (view: 'list', model:[reportingInstanceList: reportingInstanceList, reportingInstanceTotal: i, params: params])
```

The **list.gsp** is as follows:

The view is rendered but the default sorting is not working.

```
<g:sortableColumn class="tabtitle" property="id" title="Id" titleKey="reporting.id" />
<g:sortableColumn class="tabtitle" property="company" title="Company" titleKey="reporting.company" />
```

Unfortunately the default sorting (by id, by company, etc) are not working.
Any hint why?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Comment: Do you mean that you're not able to sort at all, or it's just not sorted by default?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are asking about the sorting/order links at the top of the columns on the list page, the links are hrefs back to the controller and method that was originally used to populate the list. Plus the URLs include parameters for sort and order.  For instance:

`/tracker/bug/searchCurrentUserProject?sort=name&order=asc`

The controller method will then need to handle the sort and order values from the link:

`params.sort = params.sort ?: "priority"`

`params.order = params.order ?: "asc"`

And pass them to the database query:

`def bugList = Bug.createCriteria().list(
        sort:params.sort, 
        order:params.order, 
        max:params.max, 
        offset:params.offset) {
        eq "projectId", new Integer (params.projectId)
}`

Comment: To add: if you use dynamic finders or other GORM methods, you can just pass params object into them (i.e. Account.list(params)).

Answer (score 0):

You can add two hidden fields in your form, set them dynamically with Javascript and send them together with your form.